# Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?

Tags: support, on-topic

Is providing link to my (8 pages) proof of P=NP and asking to check my proof appropriate for a MathOverflow question?

The proof is on professional mathematician level (uses advanced logics) and does not produce a crackpot impression (except that it is short, 8 pages).

Comment: No, this is not an appropriate place for that.

Comment: [math.meta.se]: [Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35920) and [cstheory.meta.se]: [Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3103)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. It is not. This is not the purpose of this website.